# Should we allow a tag called "anti-hinduism"?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-deletion

There are some questions with the tag [anti-hinduism](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anti-hinduism)

The tag [description](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/tags/anti-hinduism/info) says:

> Anti-Hinduism is a misguided negative perception or religious intolerance against the practice and practitioners of Hinduism.

I find creation and usage of such tags disturbing.

If we allow such tags, I can imagine users in the future creating other tags like "pro-islam", "pro-single-religion" etc. and we'll start losing focus on Q & A and enter into a game of asking politically motivated questions and calling each other names.

Comment: Yeah, I agree, the anti-Hinduism tag should probably be removed.  It would have a legitimate use if there were a bunch of questions being posted about discrimination and violence that Hindus face, which I think would be a legitimate subject here just as Islamophobia is a legitimate topic on Islam.SE.  But for the time being people haven't posted such questions.

Comment: I don't think it's a wise idea to introduce this tag.

Comment: Can't we just go by some generic tag like [tag:scripture] for this question and avoid thinking about complementary tag for [tag:anti-hinduism] and just remove it from everywhere?

Comment: I have removed [tag:anti-hinduism] from the questions. Replaced it with [tag:scripture] which would be relevant to the question.

Answer (score 5):

Above discussions are fruitful,

But what i think that we have to use words for tags like this carefully which new user can easily understand and can use without offending enmasse.

[criticism](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/criticism) sounds fine in questions which are clearly appear as that they have somewhat negative perception and want to clear there thoughts.

But for other questions which did not fall in this category we can use tags like [skepticism](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/skepticism).

**Skepticism**:

> a sceptical attitude; doubt as to the truth of something.

Because i observe that most of the new user afraid of asking questions regrading their doubts they may think that they are offending someone.

Although i am relatively new user here but above are my personal thought as i am  generally a observer here.

Comment: `skepticism` is a good idea. Just to be noted, that there is a dedicated site for it: http://skeptics.stackexchange.com. However, it sounds little lighter compared to `criticism` and can workout as an addon tag.

Comment: @iammilind yup i know they have religion tag there where they ask the questions on doubt about various religions without anyone offending no one. :)

Answer (score 4):

How about a tag like:
[critique-of-hinduism](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/critique-of-hinduism) or [criticism-of-hinduism](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/criticism-of-hinduism).

Without insulting, it will provide a platform for those questions, which actually question or criticises the Hinduism itself.

<sub>Note: There is a [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Criticism_of_Hinduism) on it, but it's very specific criticism. Hence it's not related.</sub>

Comment: Great idea! A lot of questions can be posted under that tag like Jainism, Buddhism criticizing Hinduism on various philosophical topics.

Comment: I agree with the tag like this but if we only have one tag `criticism` instead of `criticism of hinduism` it might have a broader scope.

Comment: @Abhishekgurjar That idea is great. Just criticism sounds fine.

Comment: @Abhishekgurjar, actually I had thought about putting just `criticism` tag. However, later I retracted it, because people may use that tag for within Hinduism as well. For example, "criticism of Shankara", "criticism of Ramanuja", "criticism of castes" and so on. That means, they are just criticising certain specific aspect. But keeping your POV in mind, may be we can have `criticism` tag separately as well.

Comment: @iammilind I got you, but i think criticism is only serve as side tag and we can create a good tag wiki for it for when to use and how to use and also be nice policy is still applied on all stack exchange websites so i think user will already be careful in their words.

Comment: `criticism-of-hinduism` looks off-topic for me!

Answer (score 1):

According to wikipedia:

> Anti-Hinduism is a negative perception or religious intolerance against the practice and practitioners of Hinduism.

So, it is simply about against practices and practitioners of Hinduism. Now if you think Hinduism is Dharma, then anti-Hinduism is simply [Adharma](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E0%A4%85%E0%A4%A7%E0%A4%B0%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AE).

From [Srimad Bhagavat Purana](http://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_purana/bhagpur.html?lang=sa) 7.15.12:

> विधर्मः परधर्मश्च आभास उपमा छलः। 
>   अधर्मशाखाः पञ्चेमा धर्मज्ञोऽधर्मवत्त्यजेत् ॥

[Translation](http://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/7/15/12):

> There are five branches of irreligion, appropriately known as irreligion [vidharma], religious principles for which one is unfit [para-dharma], pretentious religion [ābhāsa], analogical religion [upadharma] and cheating religion [chala-dharma]. One who is aware of real religious life must abandon these five as irreligious.

**So, if you need such tag you can use tag [adarma](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adarma).** (or [dharma](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dharma) may also work)

**I think we should not use/allow tag [anti-hinduism](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anti-hinduism).**

In fact I think [anti-hinduism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-Hinduism) is modern idea and is **not** `on-topic` or in our scope of this site. Example, [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/11682/277) question was (before deletion) closed as off-topic:

> This question does not appear to be about Hindu religion, within the scope defined in the help center.

There are currently two question in our site (I've [corrected/fixed](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/posts/12302/revisions) one where this tag is used incorrectly I think) tagged to [anti-hinduism](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anti-hinduism):

1. [Wendy Doniger and the Bhagavad Gita](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/12160/277)
2. [Do Hindu texts talk about how to respond to ideology which is against Hinduism?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/11683/277)

The first one is closed as primarily opinion based which I think off-topic also. And the second one is only surviving for this tag which can be answered from Dharma-Shahtra I think but we don't need [anti-hinduism](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anti-hinduism).

Comment: `adharma` means any type of `sin` in general (within Hinduism), using the same tag for `criticism-of-hinduism` (coming from other religions) is definitely misleading.